# How to find which android devices comes under xdpi,mdpi,Idpi,xxhdpi,xhdpi

Tags: android

I want to find which android devices comes under which mdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi,etc..
I want to support ImageView width for all android devices.So, for that I wanted to mention layout width size specifically for mdpi,xxhdpi,xhdpi,etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Step One**

Take a look at this [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp) table for understanding which DPI maps to which density qualifier.

For example 0-120dpi refers to ldpi, 120-160dpi refers to mdpi and so on.

[image]
**Step Two**

Now, when how to calculator DPI/PPI of the mobile screen. There is a formula. Square root of summation of square of width px and height px divided by screen diagonal length. Check the formula in detail here [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)
[image]